# how to use props.match.params.id

Tags: reactjs

this is my App.js Component

```
  <Routes>
        <Route path='/products/:id'  element={<ProductDetails/>} />
        // other <Route />
  </Routes>
```

and this is my ProductDetails Component

```
 const ProductDetails = (props) => {

      const id = props.match.params.id

      return (
         <div>
            <h1> {id} </h1>
         </div>
      );
  };
```

but i got this error =  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

what should I do??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are using the `react-router-dom` package you can access the URL parameters using the useParams hook.

```
 import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

 const ProductDetails = (props) => {

      const { id } = useParams()

      return (
         <div>
            <h1> {id} </h1>
         </div>
      );
  };
```

official documentation: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Comment: thank you very much   it worked   

Comment: @Saye your welcome :) you can then go ahead and accept my post as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `props` like this

```
  <Routes>
        <Route path='/products/:id'  render={(props) => <ProductDetails {...props}/>} />
        // other <Route />
  </Routes>
```

Or you can use `withRouter` HOF to get the props

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const ProductDetails = (props) => {

      const id = props.match.params.id

      return (
         <div>
            <h1> {id} </h1>
         </div>
      );
  };

export default withRouter(ProductDetails);
```

Comment: @Saye, check this out!!

Comment: thank you very much 